# Wordpress nav_menu items from another menu appearing

Tags: menus, navigation

In my website i'm using two separate nav_menus, one to the legal pages and other for the main navbar...
For some reason some items of the main menu are appearing in the secondary menu, even though in the backoffice the menu is correct

`Backoffice display of the menu`

[image]

`Website screenshot displaying the menus:`

[image]

`wp query of the main menu`

```
$argsMenu = array('theme_location' => 'Main');
<?php wp_nav_menu($argsMenu); ?>
```

`wp_query of the secondary menu`

```
<?php wp_nav_menu($menuSecondary = array(
                                        'container'       => 'div',
                                        'container_class' => 'menu__secondary__content',
                                        'menu_class'      => 'menu__secondary',
                                        'echo'            => true,
                                        'items_wrap'      => '<div class="menu__secondary__wrap">%3$s</div>',
                                        'theme_location'  => 'Seconday',
                                    )); ?>
```

*Thanks in advance* , its a simple problem that is making me insane

Comment: do you have a typo in 'theme_location' => 'Seconday'? 'Seconday' instead of 'Secondary'?

Comment: this is my code :  register_nav_menus(array(
      'Main' => 'Header Menu',
      'Secondary' => 'Secondary Menu',
    ));

Comment: it was a typo , fixed it ! such a stupid mistake ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you went down this path already, but be sure [register menus and support for theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menus/):

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'Main' => 'Main Navigation',
        'Secondary' => 'Secondary Menu'
    )
);
```

And then follow your pattern of `'theme_location'  => 'Secondary'` to print your registered menu back.

Comment: Yeah i've tried that... but idk why it keeps showing menu items from other menus... currently this is my code

```
 register_nav_menus(array(
      'Main' => 'Header Menu',
      'Secondary' => 'Secondary Menu',
    ));

```

Comment: fixed it , it was a typo